# Old phpBB posts use different [quote] BBCode markup that doesn't work anymore

Tags: markup, phpbb

I restored a ten-year-old phpBB forum, and after upgrading it to 3.1.x, I noticed that the `quote` BBCode is not working correctly (but I don’t know if it worked in the old version).

If no username/URL is specified, everything’s fine:

```
[quote]…[/quote]
```

But if the username/URL is specified, the format in old posts looks like this:

```
[quote=John]…[/quote]
```

while phpBB seems to require this format (and this is also what the post editor generates):

```
[quote="John"]…[/quote]
```

So the quotes around the name/URL are missing.

How could I convert this BBCode in old posts? Or is it possible to make the version without quotation marks work in addition to the new one?

Answer (score 1):

I just hunted down the code that Nathan and I developed back when we released version 1 of phpBB and it did use both `quote=` and `quote=""`

Here is the related code, perhaps it can point you in the right direction:

```
$text = preg_replace("/\[quote=&quot;(.*?)&quot;\]/si",$bbcode_tpl['quote_username_open'], $text);
```

and for the .tpl file:

```
<!-- BEGIN quote_username_open -->
<table cellspacing="1" cellpadding="3" border="0" id="quoted-member">
    <tr>
        <td><span class="NormText"><b>{USERNAME}:</b></span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="Comments_Quote">
<!-- END quote_username_open -->
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you have a suggestion for a possible way to implement this? Should I try to edit phpBB’s definition (in core) for `quote` so that it accepts both variants? ([adding a custom BBCode](https://www.phpbb.com/support/docs/en/3.1/kb/article/adding-custom-bbcodes-in-phpbb3/) doesn’t seem to work because of the same name it would need to have)